# Existence and uniqueness non autonomous ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For the first order, non autonomous ODE

$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{x}{t}  $

I have been asked to find the general solution, and then conclude on the existence and uniqueness of solutions satisfying the initial conditions
$ x(0)=0 $ and $ x(0)\neq0 $.

I can easily solve this to give the general solution $ x(t)=Ct $ with some constant C, but am struggling to understand how too apply the existence and uniqueness theorem to this.

So far, from what I've been told by my TA, I can say that no solutions exist at $x(0)\neq0 $ because the derivative is then $ \frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{x(0)}{0} $, but I'm really struggling with the uniqueness part.

By drawing the family of lines for different constants C I can see that x(0)=0 is not a unique point as all solution lines pass through it, so does that make all the solutions non-unique? If so how do I go about proving this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution gives a *family* of functions solving the ODE.  If a solution passes through $(t,x(t)) = (a,b)$ with $a$ nonzero, then you know $C = b/a$.  In particular, $x(t) = bt/a$, and the solution approaches $(0,0)$ as $t \to 0^+$.  So the solution exists and is unique *given initial data* $(t_0,x_0)$ such that $t \in (0,\infty)$ or $t \in (-\infty,0)$.

As you've noticed, the solutions converge at $(0,0)$, demonstrating problematic behavior at the point where $dx/dt$ is discontinuous.  Of course, the equation isn't properly defined here anyway so this is not surprising, and in reality our solution $x = bt/a$ *doesn't solve the equation* at $t = 0$, since
$$ {dx\over dt} = {b\over a } \neq {x\over t} = {x(0)\over 0} \notin \mathbb{R}.$$
No solution exists for $t = 0$, regardless of your choice for $x(0)$.

We can try to patch things up by defining the problem at $t = 0$.  For example, we could write
$$ {dx \over dt} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} {x\over t} & \rm{ if } ~ t \neq 0 \\ c' & \rm{ if }~ t = 0 \end{array} \right. $$
for some constant $c'$, and $x(0) = 0$.  Then the equation makes sense at $t = 0$ and we have a chance to solve.  We find that this equation admits a solution through the origin by combining your solution with the initial data:
$$ x = c't $$
and this solution is now unique!  This is a different problem than you are solving, but perhaps it gives you an idea of how discontinuity of the coefficients defining the ODE can create a breakdown of uniqueness or solvability.